# having laravel category (slug based) posts with pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function, where i get my categories base on their `slug`

```
public function postcategoryposts($slug){
  $category = PostCategory::where('slug','=',$slug)->firstOrFail();
  return view('front.postcategory-posts', compact('category'));
}
```

Currently i'm getting my each category posts in blade like:

```
@foreach($category->posts as $post)
  {{$post->title}}
@endforeach
```

until here everything is normal, the problem is how to divide my posts into pages? I am not able to use:

```
$category = PostCategory::where('slug','=',$slug)->paginate(10);
```

because I'm using

```
firstOrFail();
```

any idea?

Comment: use limit and offset.

Comment: @SachinAghera how's that?

Comment: $category = PostCategory::where('slug','=',$slug)->limit(0)->offset(100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a function to your model to get posts and then paginate.

In your controller

```
public function postcategoryposts($slug)
{
  $category = PostCategory::where('slug','=',$slug)->firstOrFail();
  $posts = $category->getPaginatedPosts(10);
  return view('front.postcategory-posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

In your model

```
// PostCategory model
public function getPaginatedPosts($limit = 10)
{
  // Get category posts using laravel pagination method
  return Post::where('category_id', '=', $this->id)->paginate($limit);
}
```

In your blade view

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        {{ $post->title }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $posts->render() }}
```

More informations about Laravel pagination [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#configuration)

Hope it's helps you :)

Comment: `Post::where('category_slug', '=', $this->slug)` posts get `category_id`